# как получить тег фрагмента в viewpager

Tags: android-viewpager

Есть ViewPager, который отображает 2 страницы(два фрагмента). Мне нужно узнать теги этих фрагментов.

Comment: можете написать пожалуйста код...

Comment: Вообщем есть два фрагмента marina.java и julia.java, Их берет pagerAdapter,чтобы отобразить в pagerview,   в первом есть кнопка, во втором Textview и метод, который туда вставляет текст
 .Нужно из  первого фрагмента вызвать метод второго. Вот код в первом фрагменте(marina):
julia fragment = (julia) getFragmentManager
    ().findFragmentByTag
    ("Здесь нужен тег");
    if (fragment != null) {
     fragment.folder("x");//метод
    }
Разметка фрагментов обычные LinearLayot с элементами. 
Как узнать тег фрагментов(говорят их присваивает адаптер)

Comment: Да, верно говорят что теги присваивает адаптер. На счет того как  из первого фрагмента вызвать метод второго, скорее всего никак. Потому что один фрагмент не находится в памяти. Если разве что они не на одной активности. В каком виде у вас тег?

Comment: я создавал по этому примеру startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html
только у меня статистические фрагменты 
код адаптера

Answer (score 0):

В классе FragmentPagerAdapter, от которого наследуется адаптер ViewPager есть такой метод:

```
private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, long id) {
    return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + id;
}
```

Это и будет тэг фрагмента, добавленного в адаптер.